# Bootstrap Datepicker doesn't work properly when placed within a "nav" html tag

Tags: datepicker, blur, nav

On my web app, I have three navigation bars (on the left side, right side and in the bottom). They can be hidden or shown by pressing a button. On my left side nav, i have two datepickers which are used to choose a date range for the data that is shown inside the main part of the window. The datepicker works properly except for one thing. When i open the datepicker and the dates are shown and if I want to close the datepicker without choosing a date, I would normally just click anywhere else on the page and the datepicker would disappear. But the problem is that this happens only when i click somewhere on nav2 (the right nav) or nav3 (the bottom nav). So, it doesn't work when i click on the left nav (where the datepickers are placed) or in the main part of the window. Does anyone know what could cause this issue?

This is the part with the js scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rurl}/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/common.js"></script> 
<script src="${rurl}/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
<script src="${rurl}/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
```

and this is the html part where the left nav is: [jsfiddle.net/2pebcd4v](http://jsfiddle.net/2pebcd4v)

Comment: please show us your code or maybe a jsfiddle so we can help

Comment: This is the part with the js scripts:
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rurl}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="${rurl}/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="${rurl}/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="${rurl}/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"

and this is the html part where the left nav is:
http://jsfiddle.net/2pebcd4v/

Comment: I have copied the code from your comment into your question with an [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26119282/edit) by clicking the *edit* link under your question tags. It's always better to edit your question than add large amounts of information in comments